# Get all rows with a list of date between two date columns in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table named tableA which has two date columns. Currently, I am using the below query to fetch data.

"select * from tableA where IN_Date between date1 and date2"

IN_DATE is input param from the proc

Now instead of one date IN_DATE, I want to pass a list of dates but I am not sure how to update the query. Please help.

### TableA

### id date1 date2

Comment: Do you want pass these dates as a string of comma (or whatever) separated values like `2021-01-15, 2021-01-20, ...`? Or somehow else?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem

```
select * from tableA where (
    (IN_Date between date1 and date2) or 
    (IN_Date between date3 and date4) or 
    (IN_Date between date5 and date6)
)
```

Comment: columns are fixed, date1 and date2. IN_DATE instead is a list of dates passed as a comma-separated string.

Comment: date1, date2, date3, date4, date5 and date6 are list of date values not columns. if the issue is not resolved, please share sample expected output

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do simply is not possible.

The syntax of the between clause is:

... expression1 BETWEEN expression2 AND expression3 ...

Each expression must resolve to a **single** value (not a list of values). Furthermore expression2 be < expression3, otherwise results are undefined.
Where expressionN is a column name, then the single value is the value in the row currently being evaluated.

This suggests that you may be approaching this incorrectly. Please provide some sample data, and expected results. This will allow a better understanding of what you are trying to do. A description of what you are wanting to achieve would also be helpful, rather than a description of how you are trying to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a string tokenization approach like below, where the `IN_DATE` string parameter has comma separated list of dates in the form of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
select *
from tableA t
where exists
(
  select 1
  from xmltable 
  (
    'for $id in tokenize($s, ",") return <i>{normalize-space ($id)}</i>' 
    passing IN_DATE as "s"
    columns 
      tok char(10) path '.'
  ) v
  where date (to_date (v.tok, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) between t.date1 and t.date2
)
```